# How to join a total of 6 tables?

Tags: sql

I want join 6 tables:

- Table A join Table B
- Table A join Table C
- Table A Join Table D
- Table D Join Table E
- Table E Join Table F

But I can't run it:

```
SELECT   
    A.ID, A.Name, A.SName,
    B.tel, B.status,
    C.ComCode, C.Comdes,
    D.Type,
    E.Des, E.AreaDes,
    F.AreaID
FROM
    ((((Table A 
INNER JOIN 
    Table B ON A.ID = B.ID) 
INNER JOIN 
    Table C ON A.Concode = C.Comcode)
INNER JOIN 
    Table D ON A.Type = D.Type)
INNER JOIN 
    Table E ON D.Des = E.Des)
INNER JOIN 
    Table F ON E.AreaID = F.AreaID
```

Comment: **WHAT** "dialect" of SQL is this for? What **concrete** RDBMS are you using? SQL Server? Oracle? Postgresql? MySQL? Something else entirely?? Please **add a relevant tag**!

Comment: "But I can't run it" will not help us help you.  Can't run how???  No result?  Error out?  Wrong result?

Comment: Also, what's with all those brackets?

Comment: Your query would appear to do what you intend.  Hence, I don't know what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of your parentheses and table and it should be vailid SQL, so

```
SELECT ...
FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.a = b.a
INNER JOIN c ON b.b = c.a
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT   
    A.ID, A.Name, A.SName,
    B.tel, B.status,
    C.ComCode, C.Comdes,
    D.Type,
    E.Des, E.AreaDes,
    F.AreaID
FROM Table A
INNER JOIN Table B ON A.ID = B.ID
INNER JOIN Table C ON A.Concode = C.Comcode
INNER JOIN Table D ON A.Type = D.Type
INNER JOIN Table E ON D.Des = E.Des
INNER JOIN Table F ON E.AreaID = F.AreaID
```

Answer (score 0):

It will help if you tell us what you database server is e.g., SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc. When you say, "...I can't run it..." are you getting an error? If so, can you share that.

I ditched your parenthesis...

```
SELECT   
    A.ID,
    A.Name,
    A.SName,
    B.tel,
    B.status,
    C.ComCode,
    C.Comdes,
    D.Type,
    E.Des,
    E.AreaDes,
    F.AreaID
FROM
    TableA A INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.ID = B.ID 
    INNER JOIN TableC C ON A.Concode = C.Comcode
    INNER JOIN TableD D ON A.Type = D.Type
    INNER JOIN TableE E ON D.Des = E.Des
    INNER JOIN TableF F ON E.AreaID = F.AreaID
```

For clarity, I adjusted your table names (so it was clear what was Table A vs. Table B).

[image]